# For Exchange 2003, is there a way to set what servers my public folders replicate to?

Tags: exchange-2003

I adopted a junk Exchange 2003 environment.  I need to consolidate the (2) administrative groups into (1).  I've moved over the Public Folders in the top-level, but I need to clean up the replication.

Currently, the public folders are replicating to servers in the old administrative group, new administrative group, or both.  I am manually changing the replication settings for each public folder and their sub-folders, but this is time consuming.  I looked in the System Policies, and I cannot configure anything to set what servers will hold the replications.  Is there another way I can do this other than manually for all folders and sub-folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

After I moved the public folders, I needed to add replica servers from the Administrative Groups > Folders > Public Folders

I could also change the settings from the top level folder and push down those settings using the Manage settings options on each top level public folder (available in Exchange 2003 SP2).

I eventually ran into some problems with two of my servers where doing this never worked properly, but I was also having replication problems where the replicas weren't synchronized completely.  So, I ended up moving all public folder onto their own server in the same Administrative group.

I also set it up a policy for all mailbox stores to have their default public store point to this server, which also assured all my users were going to the right place for their public folders.